# Getting response from sending form in textbox

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, forms

I'm trying to make a website that automatically uses this script to get amount of bitcoin in an wallet :

```
<?php
$address = $_GET["address"];
$satbalance = file_get_contents('https://blockchain.info/q/addressbalance/'.$address.'');
$btcbal = ($satbalance) / 100000000;
echo $btcbal;
?>
```

and I'm trying to make page that has my clients username and password in textarea box and when I enter the bitcoin wallet address from my user to check the balance from multiple input boxes and show the value in the box in front of address box.

[Image of the page that needs this job done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sd3dl.png)

How can I get the response from the form and display in another box or variable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the fields in a form tag and submit to the same page.

Using your code example, this example show a simple form and handling the POST with PHP. This hasn't been tested but is an example of how to handle a post using the `$_POST` super global.

```
<?php
$btcbal = null;

// Check if there is POST data
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $satbalance = file_get_contents('https://blockchain.info/q/addressbalance/'.$address.'');
    $btcbal = ($satbalance) / 100000000;
}

?>
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <input type="text" name="btc_address">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<p>Balance: <?php echo $btcbal ? $btcbal : 'N/A'; ?></p>
```